# Raspberry PI loses IPv4 address randomly but keeps IPv6 address

Tags: networking, pi-4

For quite a long time now my Raspberry PI 4 has been loosing connectivity every few weeks. However the last 2 weeks or so my Raspberry PI has been losing connectivity almost daily. I'm running quite a standard setup on it with docker, portainer and some other docker containers. Whenever this happens I simply power cycle the device and everything works again.

I got a bit fed up with this so I started doing some investigation. I ran the `ip addr` command and saw this:
[image]

As can be seen here for some reason the IPv4 address is missing. I tried unplugging the network cable and plugging it back in again but this didn't fix the issue.
I then saw that it did still have an IPv6 address, so I tried to SSH to the PI using that address which unexpectedly worked perfectly.

I then tried to refresh the IP address by running `sudo dhclient -r` and `sudo dhclient`. This fixed the problem.

I have no idea why this issue happens though, so I'm looking for some help :).

Edit: As requested, here's the information on the version of Linux running on my PI:
[image]

`uname -m: aarch64`

Edit2:
I've also added a screenshot of the `service --status-all` command:
[image]

Edit3:
Here's the output of the `systemctl status dhcpcd.service` command:
[image]

It seems like the error `route socket overflowed - learning interface state` is the problem here. What could be the cause for this?

Edit4:
I've now tried this workaround, hopefully this fixes the issue:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4092#issuecomment-774512217

Comment: As you haven't said what OS or how it is configured no one can say. Raspberry Pi OS  doesn't use `dhclient` although it will renew leases. Should not be necessary with a normal `dhcpcd` setup.

Comment: I've added information on what version of Raspberry Pi OS it's running. Could it be that something is configured incorrectly regarding dhcp then? I don't think I've manually installed dhclient but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: DO NOT post illegible pictures of text - post text.

Comment: Did this `dhcpcd.conf` workaround solve the issue? I'm experiencing exactly the same thing with a very similar setup; PI4, 64bit Raspberry OS, Docker with Portainer and a bunch of small containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with DHCPCD & Docker on Raspberry, as you already found by yourself. The full discussion is here: [Raspberry Pi 4: DHCPCD route socket overflowed](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4092). Basically, dhcpcd can be flooded when renewing IP addresses if too many interfaces are present. This is the case when Docker is installed and many containers/networks/services are running. In addition, docker take care of IP addresses and routing on its virtual network, so DHCPCD doesn't need to handle them.

The solution is to configure dhcpcd to ignore all interfaces whose name start with `veth` (Docker virtual interfaces).

Edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and append the following line to the end

```
denyinterfaces veth*
```

Then restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

Reference: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4092#issuecomment-774512217